# Log DNS queries (Source IP, Record Type, Hostname) using iptables

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, iptables, logging

I'm looking for a way to log DNS queries using iptables for vpn users.

What I'm looking for is to record in the syslog the source IP, the Record type and the domain name for new DNS queries.

I've had a look at http://software.klolik.org/xt_dns/ but that doesn't seem to be able to log the actual lookup name used in the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be `iptables`? It seems like using a wrong tool for the job. Maybe you're better off with using some sort of traffic analyzer?

Comment: no, not at all, it could be another tool as long as its not too heavy.. I already have a custom netfilter module running so I was thinking of writing some code in there but if there are any solutions that already exist it would save me the time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want some sort of pdns tool.
For example this genious one: https://github.com/gamelinux/passivedns
It is very lightweight, and runs by listening on the traffic on your interface.

It will log DNS requests like this:

```
1371572390.617141||195.225.XX.YYY||208.78.71.16||IN||github.com.||A||204.232.175.90||300||1
```

The format here is:

```
timestamp||dns-client ||dns-server||RR class||Query||Query Type||Answer||TTL||Count
```

Comment: looks very interesting.. because it is looking at the interface I presume it does not need the DNS server on the box? for example if my VPN clients use 8.8.8.8 for their DNS I can still log the lookups going through?

Comment: In theory, yes. Although I have not tested that myself.